# Integrate sending of a moderator message into the suspension process

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-abilities, account-suspension

When a moderator suspends a user, he/she is supposed to send a message to explain the suspension, but under the current system, sending a message is a completely separate process from the suspension itself. It'd be a helpful reminder **if clicking the "Suspend" button** (or whatever it was, I forget the label) **took you straight to the moderator message page**.

Hopefully I'm not pushing my luck with this, but it'd be even better if the text box for composing the message were filled with a template corresponding to the reason for suspension. Obviously this would require there to be a menu of typical suspension reasons, like the menu we get when closing a question or sending a message.

Comment: Most of the pre-made moderator messages are usually for being sent prior to the user getting suspended. Ideally, their first warning that their behavior is bad and that they should stop before action has to be taken. As such, in most scenarios, wouldn't this message just be a repeat?

Comment: @Grace At least one of the existing templates includes a message along the lines of "you've been suspended for X days". I don't think they're intended to only be sent as warnings.

Comment: @Anna I didn't mean to imply that was their only purpose (and on review, more of them seem to be post-suspension than I recalled), just that it seems like most suspension-worthy offenses tend to merit contact at an earlier point, which is typically done with this system. The potential redundancy in the second portion of this request doesn't feel productive to me, is all.

Comment: @Grace Fair enough. I've only sent out messages that accompanied a suspension (sock puppetry, evading suspension, that sort of thing).

Comment: @Grace Note: True, some of the templates are for pre-suspension warnings, but even in those cases we're also supposed to send a message about the suspension itself. So there are supposed to be two messages, one as a warning and one as a follow-up at the time of suspension, and it'd be nice to have templates for both.

Comment: Under "high-heat" conditions, I prefer the suspension to take effect immediately, and then I spend the new few minutes composing my thoughts for the moderator message. Sometimes this quick action is needed to prevent further damage (when you catch someone in the middle of a ragequit, for example).

Comment: @Robert: yes, that's exactly how my proposal would work. You suspend the user, and then you're taken to a page with a moderator message template which you can spend the next few minutes filling in (or writing your own message from scratch if you prefer).

Comment: It might be an educational problem.  I only suspended someone without sending a message once, and I learned my lesson.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has been implemented, though somewhat in reverse of your exact suggestion.

Now, suspension is done as part of the moderator message system, whereupon you must specify the number of days of suspension (using 0 if you're sending something like a ***SEVERE WARNING***). It is no longer possible to suspend without writing a message.