# You cannot suspend a user without contacting them anymore?

Tags: support, moderation, account-suspension

[image: No suspend]

but... but....

About half the time I suspend someone I just leave them a comment suggesting they read the faq, chiding them from re-asking the same closed question again, etc... This is usually fine for a 1-2 day suspension, whereas the contact-and-suspend is more appropriate for bigger issues, such as sockpuppetry.

Does this mean that moderator messages aren't for ***serious*** behavior problems anymore?

Comment: [Server Fault's variant of this question](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1454/so-now-mods-have-to-write-nice-emails-to-spammers/1456). Doesn't actually address your scenario, though.

Comment: Wait a minute, isn't the fact that you're *suspending them* a pretty good indication that *something serious* is goin' on?

Comment: @Shog9: Not necessarily.  Or, at least that was the impression I had before.  **for VERY serious moderation issues *only!*** implies **serious** issues.  1-2 days suspension for something obvious (f-you in a comment or something similar) wouldn't count.  Unless the implication is that *every* suspension is considered serious enough to contact the user.  Even if the user isn't registered, doesn't have their account filled out, etc.  I think there should be a second way, which was the way it was until very recently...

Comment: @Will: one problem with that was moderators (especially new ones) forgetting to notify users who *didn't* realize what they'd done. And yeah, I understand that - to you, on SO, with piles and piles of suspended users - a 1-2 day suspension doesn't seem like that big of a deal, but... to a new user, especially on a new site, it can seem like a pretty big slap in the face. I don't know all the reasoning behind this change, but I suspect [this is a big part of it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85079/integrate-sending-of-a-moderator-message-into-the-suspension-process)

Comment: Before closing the tab of this page, I clicked on the black close button at the left corner of the image you posted :/

Comment: @OscarMederos: *sucker!*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short; you are correct - this has moved home.

Suspension *is* pretty serious, at least from the perspective of someone being suspended. Combining this with a visible message is only reasonable; additionally:

- this makes the dialogue visible to other moderators, where a comment (your example above) is not so visible
- it allows (controlled) dialogue *during* suspension
- it helps with example text

In particular, writing a suspension message *can be hard*; so if there are additional common scenarios that would benefit from templating, please say. "you suck" tends to be met with hostility, so phrasing can be key.

Comment: Okay, so any suspension is now considered serious enough to contact a user.  I won't be scared by that wording anymore.